# Using Twython to Convert Multiple User IDs to User Names

Tags: python, twitter, dictionary, twython

I am trying to convert list of Twitter IDs I have into Twitter user names
According to the Twitter API document, I am able to submit multiple requests per call.
And that parameters for the input should be comma seperated.

Below are basically the core of what I'm trying to do
and the result I get is the user name for one of three IDs I submit.

Any suggestions on how I can improve this to accept multiple IDs?
I have the data = output[0]
Just because the result I get from lookup_user doesn't allow me to parse through the json fields....

```
from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython(AUTH)

samplefollower = ["259784090","136953436","1219150098"]

output = twitter.lookup_user(user_id=samplefollower)
data = output[0]
print data["screen_name"]
```

and the result of the print data["screen_name"] from the above code is obviously the screenname of the first id number jwchoi13

print output[0] is

```
{u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'default_profile_image': True, u'id': 259784090, u'verified': False, u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'profile_image_url_hddps': u'hddps://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_normal.png', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'entities': {u'description': {u'urls': []}}, u'followers_count': 33, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'C0DEED', u'id_str': u'259784090', u'profile_background_color': u'C0DEED', u'listed_count': 1, u'status': {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'Prach got exactly $100 thethaiger thedaniel1402 @ Citgo hddp://t.co/9NPf3StbZr', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 361284421875269632, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href="hddp://instagram.com" rel="nofollow">Instagram</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-87.70976901, 42.05236495]}, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': [{u'url': u'hddp://t.co/9NPf3StbZr', u'indices': [56, 78], u'expanded_url': u'hddp://instagram.com/p/cSilvXSGfv/', u'display_url': u'instagram.com/p/cSilvXSGfv/'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'id_str': u'361284421875269632', u'retweet_count': 0, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'favorited': False, u'geo': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [42.05236495, -87.70976901]}, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'lang': u'en', u'created_at': u'Sun Jul 28 00:38:13 +0000 2013', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': {u'full_name': u'Skokie, IL', u'url': u'hddps://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/4b3758bc32868265.json', u'country': u'United States', u'place_type': u'city', u'bounding_box': {u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[-87.780882, 42.003325], [-87.708661, 42.003325], [-87.708661, 42.06504], [-87.780882, 42.06504]]]}, u'contained_within': [], u'country_code': u'US', u'attributes': {}, u'id': u'4b3758bc32868265', u'name': u'Skokie'}}, u'profile_background_image_url_hddps': u'hddps://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', u'utc_offset': -21600, u'statuses_count': 15, u'description': u'Student at Northwestern University', u'friends_count': 33, u'location': u'Evanston, IL', u'profile_link_color': u'0084B4', u'profile_image_url': u'hddp://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_normal.png', u'following': True, u'geo_enabled': True, u'profile_background_image_url': u'hddp://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', u'screen_name': u'jwchoi13', u'lang': u'en', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 2, u'name': u'Jeongwoo Choi', u'notifications': False, u'url': None, u'created_at': u'Wed Mar 02 15:57:20 +0000 2011', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': u'Central Time (US & Canada)', u'protected': False, u'default_profile': True, u'is_translator': False}
```

print output is

```
[{u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'default_profile_image': True, u'id': 259784090, u'verified': False, u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'profile_image_url_hddps': u'hddps://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_normal.png', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'entities': {u'description': {u'urls': []}}, u'followers_count': 33, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'C0DEED', u'id_str': u'259784090', u'profile_background_color': u'C0DEED', u'listed_count': 1, u'status': {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'Prach got exactly $100 thethaiger thedaniel1402 @ Citgo hddp://t.co/9NPf3StbZr', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 361284421875269632, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href="hddp://instagram.com" rel="nofollow">Instagram</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-87.70976901, 42.05236495]}, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': [{u'url': u'hddp://t.co/9NPf3StbZr', u'indices': [56, 78], u'expanded_url': u'hddp://instagram.com/p/cSilvXSGfv/', u'display_url': u'instagram.com/p/cSilvXSGfv/'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'id_str': u'361284421875269632', u'retweet_count': 0, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'favorited': False, u'geo': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [42.05236495, -87.70976901]}, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'lang': u'en', u'created_at': u'Sun Jul 28 00:38:13 +0000 2013', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': {u'full_name': u'Skokie, IL', u'url': u'hddps://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/4b3758bc32868265.json', u'country': u'United States', u'place_type': u'city', u'bounding_box': {u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[-87.780882, 42.003325], [-87.708661, 42.003325], [-87.708661, 42.06504], [-87.780882, 42.06504]]]}, u'contained_within': [], u'country_code': u'US', u'attributes': {}, u'id': u'4b3758bc32868265', u'name': u'Skokie'}}, u'profile_background_image_url_hddps': u'hddps://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', u'utc_offset': -21600, u'statuses_count': 15, u'description': u'Student at Northwestern University', u'friends_count': 33, u'location': u'Evanston, IL', u'profile_link_color': u'0084B4', u'profile_image_url': u'hddp://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_normal.png', u'following': True, u'geo_enabled': True, u'profile_background_image_url': u'hddp://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', u'screen_name': u'jwchoi13', u'lang': u'en', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 2, u'name': u'Jeongwoo Choi', u'notifications': False, u'url': None, u'created_at': u'Wed Mar 02 15:57:20 +0000 2011', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': u'Central Time (US & Canada)', u'protected': False, u'default_profile': True, u'is_translator': False}, {u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'default_profile_image': False, u'id': 136953436, u'verified': False, u'profile_text_color': u'666666', u'profile_image_url_hddps': u'hddps://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1113190398/free-pictures-rollercoaster-superman-SpacePotato__1__normal.jpg', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'252429', u'entities': {u'description': {u'urls': []}}, u'followers_count': 3, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'181A1E', u'id_str': u'136953436', u'profile_background_color': u'1A1B1F', u'listed_count': 0, u'status': {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'RT @ozzyzzz: \ub4dc\ub77c\ub9c8 &lt;\ub098\uc778&gt; \ubbf8\uad6d\uc5d0\uc11c \ub9ac\uba54\uc774\ud06c. abc \ud3b8\uc131\uc774 \uc720\ub825\ud558\ub2e4\uace0. \uc88b\uc740 \uc77c\uc785\ub2c8\ub2e4. \ud5a5\ud6c4 \uc774\ub7f0 \uc2dd\uc758 \uc7a5\ub974 \ub4dc\ub77c\ub9c8\ub4e4\uc774 \ube44\uad50\uc801 \uc548\uc815\uc801\uc778 \ud658\uacbd\uc5d0\uc11c \uc7ac\uc0dd\uc0b0\ub420 \uc218 \uc788\uae38 \uae30\ub300\ud574\ubd05\ub2c8\ub2e4. hddp://t.co/WV5MHIOdOt', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 394683544024649728, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href="hddp://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [{u'id': 93787077, u'indices': [3, 11], u'id_str': u'93787077', u'screen_name': u'ozzyzzz', u'name': u'\ud5c8\uc9c0\uc6c5'}], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': [{u'url': u'hddp://t.co/WV5MHIOdOt', u'indices': [113, 135], u'expanded_url': u'hddp://media.daum.net/entertain/enews/newsview?newsid=20131027105206884', u'display_url': u'media.daum.net/entertain/enew\u2026'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'id_str': u'394683544024649728', u'retweet_count': 154, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'favorited': False, u'retweeted_status': {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'\ub4dc\ub77c\ub9c8 &lt;\ub098\uc778&gt; \ubbf8\uad6d\uc5d0\uc11c \ub9ac\uba54\uc774\ud06c. abc \ud3b8\uc131\uc774 \uc720\ub825\ud558\ub2e4\uace0. \uc88b\uc740 \uc77c\uc785\ub2c8\ub2e4. \ud5a5\ud6c4 \uc774\ub7f0 \uc2dd\uc758 \uc7a5\ub974 \ub4dc\ub77c\ub9c8\ub4e4\uc774 \ube44\uad50\uc801 \uc548\uc815\uc801\uc778 \ud658\uacbd\uc5d0\uc11c \uc7ac\uc0dd\uc0b0\ub420 \uc218 \uc788\uae38 \uae30\ub300\ud574\ubd05\ub2c8\ub2e4. hddp://t.co/WV5MHIOdOt', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 394364791457722368, u'favorite_count': 32, u'source': u'<a href="hddp://www.apple.com/" rel="nofollow">OS X</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': [{u'url': u'hddp://t.co/WV5MHIOdOt', u'indices': [100, 122], u'expanded_url': u'hddp://media.daum.net/entertain/enews/newsview?newsid=20131027105206884', u'display_url': u'media.daum.net/entertain/enew\u2026'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'id_str': u'394364791457722368', u'retweet_count': 154, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'favorited': False, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'lang': u'ko', u'created_at': u'Sun Oct 27 07:27:47 +0000 2013', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None}, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'lang': u'ko', u'created_at': u'Mon Oct 28 04:34:24 +0000 2013', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None}, u'profile_background_image_url_hddps': u'hddps://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme9/bg.gif', u'utc_offset': -18000, u'statuses_count': 5, u'description': u'', u'friends_count': 82, u'location': u'', u'profile_link_color': u'2FC2EF', u'profile_image_url': u'hddp://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1113190398/free-pictures-rollercoaster-superman-SpacePotato__1__normal.jpg', u'following': False, u'geo_enabled': False, u'profile_background_image_url': u'hddp://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme9/bg.gif', u'screen_name': u'djdoh88', u'lang': u'en', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 0, u'name': u'Doh Y Jung', u'notifications': False, u'url': None, u'created_at': u'Sun Apr 25 10:53:47 +0000 2010', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': u'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', u'protected': True, u'default_profile': False, u'is_translator': False}, {u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'default_profile_image': False, u'id': 1219150098, u'verified': False, u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'profile_image_url_hddps': u'hddps://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3306983555/b45937c4656908b89ce0efbc09ecbf2f_normal.png', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'EFEFEF', u'entities': {u'description': {u'urls': []}}, u'followers_count': 23, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'EEEEEE', u'id_str': u'1219150098', u'profile_background_color': u'131516', u'listed_count': 1, u'status': {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'#freechampagne at #themusketroom I love this place already hddp://t.co/6zoDsyWSek', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 396056308862160896, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href="hddp://instagram.com" rel="nofollow">Instagram</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [{u'indices': [0, 14], u'text': u'freechampagne'}, {u'indices': [18, 32], u'text': u'themusketroom'}], u'urls': [{u'url': u'hddp://t.co/6zoDsyWSek', u'indices': [59, 81], u'expanded_url': u'hddp://instagram.com/p/gJm7XRKia7/', u'display_url': u'instagram.com/p/gJm7XRKia7/'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'id_str': u'396056308862160896', u'retweet_count': 0, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'favorited': False, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'lang': u'en', u'created_at': u'Thu Oct 31 23:29:17 +0000 2013', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None}, u'profile_background_image_url_hddps': u'hddps://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif', u'utc_offset': -18000, u'statuses_count': 93, u'description': u'Born in Korea, Grew up in Jersey,\r\nWent to college in Chicago (well Chicago Suburbs)\r\nand Currently working in NYC', u'friends_count': 214, u'location': u'New York, NY', u'profile_link_color': u'009999', u'profile_image_url': u'hddp://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3306983555/b45937c4656908b89ce0efbc09ecbf2f_normal.png', u'following': False, u'geo_enabled': False, u'profile_banner_url': u'hddps://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1219150098/1361808819', u'profile_background_image_url': u'hddp://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif', u'screen_name': u'lodysseedohmer', u'lang': u'en', u'profile_background_tile': True, u'favourites_count': 2, u'name': u'Doh', u'notifications': False, u'url': None, u'created_at': u'Mon Feb 25 16:03:30 +0000 2013', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': u'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', u'protected': False, u'default_profile': False, u'is_translator': False}]
```

Comment: Please post the output of `print output`.

Comment: please read about [lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in python

Comment: Yeah my guess is I have to somehow convert the list to dictionaries but I can't seem to translate the list of three jsons into one...

Answer (score 1):

Do it like follows:

```
from twython import Twython

#Auth steps
twitter = Twython(AUTH)
samplefollower = ["259784090","136953436","1219150098"]

#We create a comma separated string from the previous list
comma_separated_string = ",".join(samplefollower)

#Now, we query twitter with the comma separated list
output = twitter.lookup_user(user_id=comma_separated_string)
username_list=[]

#Loop through the results
for user in output:
    username_list.append(user['screen_name'])
print username_list
```

This program will display:

```
[u'jwchoi13', u'djdoh88', u'lodysseedohmer']
```